# angular динамическое добавление

Tags: angularjs

имеется:

```
<span id="test_span" ng-model='test'>123</span>
```

как динамически добавить в html строку `<p> {{test}} </p>`?

Comment: что значит динамически? `ng-model` - не работает со спаном, эта директива только с полями ввода работает

Comment: @Grundy, динамически, то есть мне нужно их добавлять каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Раньше не работало с contenteditable, писали отдельную директиву

Comment: [например](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28583651/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо большое, а Вы могли бы еще подсказать, как добавить строку 
    <p> {{ test }} </p>
с помощью js и jquery, потому что 
$('.selected-container').append('<p> {{ test }} </p>') добавляет строку с текстом {{test}}

Comment: а на чем ты все-таки делаешь? для jquery Тебе не надо ` {{ test }} ` просто нужную строку сразу собирай: `append(\`<p> ${test} </p>\`)` где `test` это твоя переменная. Но есть ты все-таки используешь ангуляр - то только больше запутаешься

Comment: @Grundy, Давайте я обьясню задание: это текстовый редактор, где можно выделить текст и он переместится в другой контейнер, но при его изменении в первом контейнере он должен измениться и во втором. Поэтому когда текст выделяют, я хочу обернуть его в див с ng-model=test и во втором контейнере добавить <p> {{test}} </p>, а как это сделать без ангулара я не понимаю

Comment: там и с ангуляром проблема будет

Comment: с чем именно будет?